ThinkVision M14T Touchscreen Touch function without Alt Mode USB-C on a Zotac Zbox Nano CI547
Summary: I want to find a solution to use the touchscreen function of a M14T USB-C display with a PC that does not feature USB-C Alt mode connector.
Details:
Setup:

PC: Zotac Zbox Nano CI547 mini-pc (https://www.zotac.com/de/product/mini_pcs/ci547-nano)

Intel® Core™ i5-7200U
Intel® HD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2)
has traditional HDMI and Display Port, but no USB-C Alt-mode display port


Display: ThinkVision M14T Touchscreen (https://www.lenovo.com/de/de/p/accessories-and-software/monitors/office/62a3uat1wl)

has 2x USB-C Alt mode connectors
this are the only connectors the display has


Display connected to the PC through a Display-port to USB-C adapter

Brand: "Basesailor"
https://www.amazon.de/Micro-USB-HDMI-Eingang-3-1-Ausgang-konverter-Thunderbolt/dp/B09LGVNXPK (bought it here)
https://www.newegg.com/p/3C6-04MW-00023?srsltid=AfmBOor9OuhbS_DsTJsLt7-RmAaayITKyPxnBlapwomHtrji_IrqWrhX)


OS: Ubuntu 24.10

recently installed using a traditional HDMI display
kernel: Linux 6.11.0-9-generic



Status-Quo:
The display works well, but unfortunately the PC does not have a USB-C port with display-port (Alt mode). As I indicated above, I use a HDMI to USB-C adapter to hook the display to the PC. Through this setup I obviously do not have touch functionality.
Here is what I see in general about the display:
$ modinfo hid_multitouch | head
filename:       /lib/modules/6.11.0-9-generic/kernel/drivers/hid/hid-multitouch.ko.zst
license:        GPL
description:    HID multitouch panels
author:         Benjamin Tissoires <benjamin.tissoires@gmail.com>
author:         Stephane Chatty <chatty@enac.fr>
srcversion:     CC4AB5333F9B14CDCC32018
alias:          hid:b*g0004v*p*
alias:          hid:b*g0002v*p*
alias:          hid:b0003g0004v000018D1p00005030
alias:          hid:b*g*v000018D1p00005028

lsmod | grep touch
hid_multitouch         36864  0
hid                   266240  4 usbhid,hid_multitouch,hid_generic,hid_lenovo

It looks like some people managed to get a setup working with an adapter solution: https://www.reddit.com/r/UsbCHardware/comments/z9din4/adapter_or_cable_to_enable_touch_function_of/
The adapter they are using is quite expensive, but if no other solutions found, I might give it a try as well.
My question is:
Is there a chance that I could get the touchscreen working by running the display through the Displayport-to-USB-C connector I have and connecting the 2nd USB-C port on the display to a USB (USB-C) port on the Zbox -- I have tried this but it does not work plug-and-play.
Any insight is well appreciated!
Thank you!
